# How to force bootstrap modal to appear at the top of the screen (not in the center)?

Tags: position, bootstrap-modal

How to force bootstrap modal to appear at the top of the screen (not in the center) ?

Thank you.

Comment: I have only ever seen a Bootstrap modal appear at the top of the screen. There's a bit of space between the top border and the very top of the page but Bootstrap doesn't vertically center modals. The default code should give you what you want.

Comment: @BSMP hmm, my bootstrap centers modals vertically... I only get what i want if I set the inner content height to the big number like 700-800px. Ok, I'll keep trying.